# How do I find size and font UIActionSheet's text?

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, uifont

I'm creating my own ActionSheet class and I need to emulate size and font UIActionSheet's text.

How do I find size and font UIActionSheet's text?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can't. Unless you hack its **subViews**.
UIActionSheet is a SubClass of UIView.
Gothrough all of its subView and their subVIew, and find any view which is kind of class UIButton, for that button view,get the textFont size.

Comment: You should also have a look at http://revealapp.com. Will help you for that and much more (yeah, I'm in love with it).